# How to calculate special vector notation?

Tags: javascript, math, vector, calculation

I have some problems verifying an already calculated bill in javascript. 
I gave **some formulas and 2 vectors** - but no matter how I calculate, I don't get the right result.

I would be happy if someone could discover my careless mistake and help me, because at the moment I am really helpless.

1. These vector are given:

   [image]
2. These are the formulas for calculating the two angles angles *(alpha and beta)*:

[image: img1]

3. This is the basic formula for calculation the vectors scale:
   [image: formula1]

Here you can find the result of the calculation (I'm not getting the same result):

[image: omg3]

---

This is my javascript code:

```js
let u = [1, -0.2]
let v = [0.5, 0.8]

let mg_u = Math.sqrt(u[0] ** 2 + u[1] ** 2)
let mg_v = Math.sqrt(v[0] ** 2 + v[1] ** 2)
let sc_uv = u[0] * v[0] + u[1] * v[1]

let a = Math.sqrt((mg_v ** 2 - mg_u ** 2 + Math.sqrt((mg_v ** 2 - mg_u ** 2) ** 2 + 4 * (sc_uv ** 2))) / 2)
let b = (-sc_uv) / a
console.log(`alpha: ${a} (valid)`)
console.log(`beta: ${b} (valid)`)

let u_r = [-u[1], u[0]]
let v_r = [-v[1], v[0]]

let scale = Math.sqrt(mg_u ** 2 + a ** 2) /
  Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt((v_r[0] - b * u_r[0]) ** 2 + (v_r[1] - b * u_r[1]) ** 2) ** 2 + mg_u ** 2 + mg_v ** 2)
console.log(`scale: ${scale} (probably not valid)`)

let direction = [
  v_r[0] - b * u_r[0],
  v_r[1] - b * u_r[1],
]
console.log(`direction: ${direction} (not valid)`)
```

Comment: I had a quick go at calculating the 'so that' using the values supplied in the example and I don't get the same answer, but I could be doing it wrong...  is the example you are using wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the example and it's value are correct. But if we both have the same mistake maybe it is. This would explain a lot.

Comment: The given final result is indeed incorrect, or at least inconsistent with the other values. The ratio of the components of `v_r - b * u_r` is `-0.5822...` from the given intermediate values, but `-0.4904...` from the result.